# Can WindowTester be integrated with some other tool to make it work with Android?

Tags: android, window-tester

Can I make Windows Tester 6 to test UI for Android?. I looked this up on its site and it says - **WindowTester Pro is a UI test generation tool for testing SWT and Swing Java applications**

Answer (score 2):

WindowTester does not support Android UI testing. As the site states, it currently only supports SWT and Swing.

It's open source and might be extended, but this would take a considerable amount of effort.

I'd suggest to use a Android specific UI testing tool like [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) instead.